# Overriding Registration Form (SonataUserBundle) since Symfony2 Update to 2.8

Tags: symfony, sonata, sonata-user-bundle, symfony-2.8

After updating symfony2 with the dependencies to 2.8 I get the following error message when trying to override the sonata user bundle registration form:

```
The field type "Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType" is not registered with the service container.
```

If I switch back to Symfony 2.7 everything works again.

My services.yml:

```
sonata.user.registration.form.type:
    class: My\Bundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
    arguments: [ "%fos_user.model.user.class%" , "@service_container"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: sonata_user_registration }
```

In my controller the following line triggers the error:

```
$form = $this->container->get( 'sonata.user.registration.form' );
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any resources on this subject (i.e. if there are any changes in overriding the registration form since the latest version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this isn't a bug, but a new feature. You have to use the build() and boot() methods in your bundle to register your FormType via FormHelper::registerFormTypeMapping.

Comment: Can you show a code example? I'm having the same problem and don't understand what you mean exactly! thanks

Comment: You can find a code sample here: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#symfony3-supports
It's important to include your bundle AFTER the bundle that contains the form type you want to override (in your AppKernel).